# How to add new field to current logged in user (Meteor.user())?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to use [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/docs/#start) library to implement audio calling. I want the user to be able to call specific user based on his peerId. The only way I could come up with is to store the current logged in peerId in his document in the database.

My question is, how can I add new field to the `Meteor.user()` document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user database is accessible via `Meteor.users` as specified in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users).  Further reading in the [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data) explains that any field can be added to a user document, so you could just set up your own object at root document level to store peer connection info.  The `accounts` package is set up so that the `profile` field of the user document can be updated from the client by the logged-in user, unless a `deny` access rule has been set up.  So, you could do what you're asking with something like:

`Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { 'profile.peerId': desiredPeerId } })`